# what exactly does "という" mean in "健康になったという人"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between "健康になったという人" and "健康になった人"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This という can be interpreted in two ways. The one indicates 同格・内容説明(apposition・explanation of the following word). Another indicates a short form of と言うことだ(It is said).

So 健康になったという人 means the same as 健康になった人 or "A person who is said to have become healthy".

There are some usage of という. This link would help you.　[The という in things like 〜ということ・〜というの・〜という感じ・〜というわけ etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12441/the-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86-in-things-like-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e6%84%9f%e3%81%98-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%82%8f%e3%81%91-etc)

Comment: I don't know why I feel like using という adds a layer of uncertainty, like 健康になった人 (A person who became healthy) , 健康になったという人 (A person whos is said to have become healthy). Like it makes it more indirect and a not 100% sure kind of thing. I'm not sure if that's right or not though

Comment: @ Felipe Oliveira Thank you for your advice. I noticed that it can be interpreted as your suggestion. I edited my answer.